# How do I go about discussing a patenable product with a potential partner?

Tags: public-disclosure, non-disclosure-agreements

I met a possible partner who has solid business experience and seems well-connected. He appears to be the perfect compliment, but given the changes in patent law, I am afraid to start a discussion about my invention with him. I don't have a patent and can't justify legal expenses this early on.

Does an NDA provide enough protection in this case? What else can I do to protect my IP other than a NDA?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Ask Patents! I happen to be a moderator over on [startups.se], so I was the one to handle your migration flag. I've made a couple edits to your post--nothing substantial--but hopefully we can get you an answer. If you have any questions about the migration process or our site, please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a standard Non-Disclosure Agreement is typically enough to protect your idea. However, NDA's do have time limits, and once they expire they offer no protection at all. A good option in this case is to prepare a Provisional Patent Application, which, once filed, will give you a full year to publish your full Application and will also serve to clearly establish your Priority Date as Inventor.

If your potential business partner offers other important ideas that ultimately end up in the patent, then you may need to add him as co-inventor, which would grant him rights to use and practice the invention.